# Including empty lines using pattern

Tags: bash, awk

My problem is the following: I have a text file where there are no empty lines, now I would like to include the lines according to the *pattern file* where 1 means print the line without including a new line, 0 - include a new line. My text file is :

```
apple
banana
orange
milk
bread
```

Thу *pattern file* is :

```
1
1
0
1
0
1
1
```

The desire output correspondingly:

```
apple
banana

orange

milk
bread
```

What I tried is:

```
for i in $(cat pattern file);
do
  awk -v var=$i '{if var==1 {print $0} else {printf "\n" }}' file;
done.
```

But it prints all the lines first, and only after that it changes `$i`

Thanks for any prompts.

Comment: There's nothing in the `awk` command that makes it select a particular line of the file.

Comment: @H_squared He's using `$i` in `bash`, not in `awk`.

Comment: How did you ever end up in a situation where you have this set of inputs?  Seems like you are barking down the flagpole.

Comment: Sorry for the detour, but @tripleee, I have to ask ... I love the sound of the expression "barking down the flagpole" --- but I'm not sure what it means!

Comment: Just a twist on the familiar idiom "barking up the wrong tree".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allow multiple 0 between 1

Self documented code

```
awk '# for file 1 only 
     NR==FNR {
      #load an array with 0 and 1 (reversed due to default value of an non existing element = 0)
      n[NR]=!$1
      # cycle to next line (don't go furthier in the script for this line)
      next
      }
     # at each line (of file 2 due to next of last bloc)
     {  
       # loop while (next due to a++) element of array = 1
       for(a++;n[a]==1;a++){
          # print an empty line
          printf( "\n")
          }
       # print the original line
       print
     }' pattern YourFile
```

- need of inversion of value to avoid infinite new line on last line in case there is less info in pattern than line in data file
- multiple 0 need a loop + test
- unsynchro between file number of pattern and data file is a problem using a direct array (unless it keep how much newline to insert, another way to doing it)

Comment: NeronLeVelu, thank you for your answer! If possible, could you please explain the meaning of the expression 'n[NR]=!$1' and why do we need two 'a++'  in a loop?

Comment: added the comment in code directly, it load the pattern file in an array for a leter use when reading textfile

Answer (score 2):

Read the pattern file into an array, then use that array when processing the text file.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { newlines[NR] = $0; next}
     { print $0 (newlines[FNR] ? "" : "\n") }' patternfile textfile
```

Comment: I forgot to add the normal newline, fixed it.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to understand the syntax of the previous answer, but I didn't manage. Now its more clear for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but I present it as an alternative to your traditionally awk-y solutions:

```
paste -d, file.txt <(cat pattern | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's,1 0,10,g' | tr ' ' '\n' | tr -d '1') | tr '0' '\n' | tr -d ','
```

The output looks like this:

```
apple
banana

orange

milk
bread
```

Answer (score 1):

Inverse of Barmar's, read the text into an array and then print as you process the pattern:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {fruit[NR]=$0; next} {print $0?fruit[++i]:""}' fruit.txt pattern.txt 
apple
banana

orange

milk
```

Comment: Jas, thank you for your solution! If I may ask, could you please explain the second braces :  {print $0?fruit[++i]:""}, because I didn't manage to find such expression in awk UserGuide.

Comment: @MirrG it print the next line from fruit array (copy of textfile content)  if pattern = 1, if not it print an empty line. If it print the fruit, it also increment the index for reaching next fruit in array (for next line)

Answer (score 1):

For an answer using only bash:

```
i=0; mapfile file < file
for p in $(<pattern); do
   ((p)) && printf "%s" "${file[i++]}" || echo
done
```